# (c) in Exercise 2.3 Lee's Riemannian Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

This is an exercise from Lee's Riemannian geometry.
The $\Longrightarrow$ is easy, but I don't get the direction $\Longleftarrow$ at all.

Exercise 2.3. Suppose $M \subset \widetilde{M}$ is an embedded submanifold.

(c) If $\tilde{X}$ is a vector field on $\widetilde{M}$, show that $\tilde{X}$ is tangent to $M$ at points of $M$ if and only if $\widetilde{X} f|_M=0$ whenever $f \in C^{\infty}(\widetilde{M})$ is a function that vanishes on $M$.

Here is my proof for $\Longrightarrow$.

Let $i: M \rightarrow \widetilde{M}$ be the inclusion map.
For the $\widetilde{X}$ tangent to $M$, there is a $X \in TM$ such that $i_*X=\widetilde{X}$ on $M$.
Then $\widetilde{X} f|_M = (i_{*}X)f = X (fi)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* First of all, note that "being tangent to $M$" is a local condition. Because $M$ is embedded, you can find local "slice" coordinates $(x_1,\dots,x_m, x_{m+1},\dots,x_{m+k})$ so that $M = \{x_{m+1}=\dots=x_{m+k}=0\}$. Consider the action of $\widetilde X$ on these coordinate functions.